# Class.forName for array of custom objects

Tags: java, arrays

Suppose I have a class `Point`. When I do:

```
Class myClass = Class.forName("Point");
```

It works. But when I do:

```
Class myNewClass = Class.forName("[L" + "Point");
```

It does not work. What can be done to make this work?

Comment: can you be more elaborate what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I do not believe this works as you believe it would be. It would try to load a class named `[LPoint`, instead of loading `Point` and making it an array. I believe what you want is: `Array.newInstance(myClass, length)` if I understand the usage of `myNewClass` properly.

Comment: @DaftPunk: I believe the OP is trying to get a `Class` instance representing the type `Point[]`.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: This might be a X-Y problem. Reflection is used either to dynamically examine a given object and its structure. Even for arrays you don't need `forName` then. Or it is used to create a new instance. In that case @Daft Punk's `Array.newInstance` is way better. So perhaps the real solution is to step back and rethink the problem instead of doing strange name encoding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot a `;`

```
Class.forName("[L" + "Point" + ";");
```

In [java.lang.Class.getName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29):

> If this class object represents a class of arrays, then the internal form of the name consists of the name of the element type preceded by one or more `'['` characters representing the depth of the array nesting. The encoding of element type names is as follows:
>
> ```
> Element Type       │ Encoding
> ───────────────────┼────────────
> class or interface │ Lclassname;
> ```